# Excel Formula Vlookup, Index and Match

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have tried a few iterations of Vlookups, Index and Match but can't figure out how to solve the following.

[Example Image of the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsAwV.jpg)
[image: Example Image of the desired result]

I have three columns Name, Match Field and Result. I need a formula that will look at the values in Match Field and if the value is found in the Name Column it will Write the name of the Match Field in the Result Column.

I have attached an Image of what I would like the result to be like.

Comment: Hi David  I tried a few vlookup and match formulas from the web and trying to tweak them for my needs, but since I suck completely with this I could not get anything to work. I thought I'll try and find some help from the pros.

Comment: while many ppl here could do this with their eyes closed, showing some previous effort (even if it failed) is good form. It also gives us a reference point so we can explain e.g., what you did wrong, or determine how much detail we should provide in the answer. :)

Comment: Hi David thank you for the advise, I will remember to save my previous efforts next time and add the to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `Result` column (C2)

```
    =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3&" *",A$2:B$5,1,FALSE),"")
```

This will match it properly (first word in column `A`) but it will bring in the name from Column `A`.

UPDATE: not a pretty one but will format as required

```
    =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2&" *",A$2:B$5,1,FALSE),"")="","",B2)
```

Comment: just realised your `Match field` and `Name` are not the same. Will follow up with a solution

Comment: You should probably use the optional  `range_lookup` parameter in the VLOOKUP function, unless you know for certain that the data is sorted alphabetically; otherwise returns an approximate match, which is probably not expected. Also consider wrapping this in `Iferror` function.

Comment: Thanks @DavidZemens, `rangelookup` & `iferror` added.

Comment: Hi David, this is almost want I need. So Column A contains Name and Surname and Column B a lookuplist of Name, If the Name from Column B is Found in Column A then return the Name Value in Column C. If you have a solution to this. It will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for what you sent me this is a good starting point an hopefully I can figure it our from here. Kind regards, Aleck

Comment: @AleckSwart I suggest you use this opportunity to [revise your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40498880/edit) including more detail, and example of your data & expected outputs. Right now, it's not clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: Thanks David, I will do so. Kind regards,